# Jetty custom format log pattern in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

We have upgraded spring boot application to 2.5 and as a result jetty is upgraded to 9.X

With this update server.jetty.accesslog.time-zone is no longer a valid entry in application.property.
We need timezone in IST, right now it is coming in GMT (default). Any idea how to set it to IST.

Before upgrade access.log
`0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Jul/2021:14:31:10 +0530] "POST /hotels/generate/partial/v1/refresh-hotel-tagging HTTP/1.1" 200 7  211960`

I tried with `server.jetty.accesslog.custom-format= %{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss SSS}t`
which gives : `[15/Sep/2021:13:11:47 942]`

We need the log format as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in the javadoc on `CustomRequestLog`

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.43.v20210629/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html

```
%{format|timeZone|locale}t

The time that the request was received. Optional parameter in one of the following formats {format}, {format|timeZone} or {format|timeZone|locale}.  
   Format Parameter: (default format [18/Sep/2011:19:18:28 -0400] where the last number indicates the timezone offset from GMT.)
       Must be in a format supported by DateCache
  
   TimeZone Parameter:
       Default timeZone GMT
       Must be in a format supported by TimeZone.getTimeZone(String)
  
   Locale Parameter:
       Default locale Locale.getDefault()
       Must be in a format supported by Locale.forLanguageTag(String)
```

So use the timezone you want in your format ...

```
%{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss SSS|IST}t
```

You can also optionally specify the Locale (which is useful to specify. example if you decide to use long names for months)

Using IST + Japanese locale

```
%{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss SSS|IST|ja}t
```